# How to append content into a twitter-bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

How can I append a ne DOM element into a bootstrap popover. I have to render a small charts, using Highcharts, which should be displayed into popover, so I cant use just a string for content attribute.

So the main problem is, how to get the popover element after `$el.popover()` was called.

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable the html option of the popover instance, for example,

```
$('.popover-with-html').popover({ html : true });
```

Comment: This will not work as I has to append a DOM element not just a HTML String.

Comment: ok, check this working fiddle http://bootply.com/80317 , may it will help you, I'm not sure, this what you are expecting

Comment: Do you even read a question before answering? TS asks how to append an html element to the popover with all data and events. You can't use a simple string for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with

```
$el.popover({
  content: $('.chart')
})
```

where .chart is your chart (or whatever) element.